# Chart.js disappears on Android

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, html5-canvas, chart.js

I am using [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org) ( the branch with tooltips ) to display some charts and everything is good on Chrome on PC.

This problem only appears on Android (tested it on KitKat, Nexus 7, Chrome 31): after the charts complete the loading animations they are not rendered corectly anymore ( only part of the grid is beng shown and no data ).

Here is the page I have tested on: http://files.tips4design.com/wordpress/?p=7

As you can see the Pie chart is the only one displayed correctly after animation is complete.

I have tested this page on iOS7 (iPhone 4) and everything went ok.

**LE:** The same bug also appears on Nexus 7 on Opera.

Comment: Works fine in Galaxy Nexus Android 4.3 inside SoClient App. Also works fine in default browser. But breaks in the same way at Google Chrome version 31. It seems to me like chrome "bug", missing extra code to run or browser preference? Have you tried chrome debug tool for mobiles?

Comment: I wanted to debug by connecting my Nexus to the PC but I had to install so many programs in order to make it work that I gave up. It's odd that the remaining canvas that is being drawn is not always the same size, so I also tend to think that it's a Chrome bug as the Chart.js canvas drawing does not take in consideration the scroll of the page, but if you scroll while the animation is playing, the resulted canvas would differ.

Comment: Did you test it with the native browser?

Comment: Isn't Chrome the default browser on Google Nexus 7?

Answer (score 1):

I probe it in Chrome/Firefox/Native Browser in Nexus 5 with android Kit kat and goes nice.

It seems a render memory problem of opera. (I detect some bad memory handle in opera mobile with other canvas animation like highcharts)

Regards.